# Div element not showing up after insertHtml

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

```
Word.run(function (context) {
var currElement = context.document.getSelection();
currElement.insertHtml('<div id="xyz">abc</div>', "After");
const body = context.document.body;
const bodyHtml = body.getHtml();
context.sync().then(() => {console.log(bodyHtml.value)});}
```

While printing out the html of the document after calling `context.sync()`, it doesn't display div at all. It displays `<p class=MsoNormal>abc</p>` instead.

However, the text is displayed with a paragraph tag. How do you display the div tag with the id/class name when you print the html of the document?

Comment: Hi! Please [edit] your question and add a [mre]. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `context.sync()` ? Please see [ask] / [tour] about creating a [mre].

Comment: @0stone0 - It's part of the Office JavaScript API (which is tagged, sort of -- edit: and now properly :-) ).

Comment: I have made the edits above which should answer your question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is innerHtml a method of Range object?I couldn't see it in documentation

Comment: @agretsuko - Gah! It's `insertHtml`, not `innerHtml`. Sorry, typo in the comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder got it. Have you faced the above issue before?